# How to open a local file in html?

Tags: html, button

Hi i started learning html a say or two ago and i was just messing around with some features when i thought of making a website which stored my school stuff in a arranged manner then i wanted to make a button that opens a local file but i just couldn't make it happen but i tried searching it on web but nothing worked for me
here is the code

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>E</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        </head>
    <body>
        <style>body{background-image: url(x.jpg);
        background-size: cover;}  
        </style> <div id="red">
        <button><a src="C:\Users\laksh\Mywebsite\jkoj.html">jkoj</a></button>
       </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It's href not src.

Comment: What they said, on your anchor tag.

Comment: And you should NEVER put <a> inside <button>.

Answer (score 1):

don't use `src` attribute in `a` tag, use `href` in place of `src`

Comment: try to give relative path, instead of absolute path, with `href`

Comment: Dude I started html like yesterday

Comment: No problem, relative path is "How you can go to other file from current file", like, if your 'jkoj' file is in same folder then use `href="./jkoj.html"` and if it is in other folder go back 1 step with `../` go to the folder in which your other file is stored.

Comment: It worked thank you so much i was in vs code and just copied relative path and pasted it i knew that relative path exists but didnt know how to use it

Comment: if you still want to use absolute path, use `file:///` before your path, but it would not work with live server.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh thanks i was using live server so it wont work but hey thanks for fixing the issue